# Un Formulario para dos tablas

Tags: laravel

Buenas tardes, la pregunta es la siguiente:

Teniendo el modelo: 
Users => atributos: name, email, password
User_profiles => atributos: last_name, ciudad, telefono, user_id

Necesito agregar en el formulario de registro el campo **last_name**, y cree un registro en la tabla **user_profiles** el **user_id** y el **last_name**

No se si debo agregar al en el modelo de **User** para el registro de los **parametros** del modelo **user_profile**

Como se llama esta acción?

Agradecido de antemano por la respuesta.

Saludos.

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo de lo que has trabajado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que estas separando las cosas en 2 tablas distintas? Puedes dejarlo todo en la misma tabla

en la migracion de create user pon algo asi:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('ciudad');
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

y en tu modelo User

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'last_name', 'ciudad', 'telefono'
];
```

con eso ya cuando hagas User::create($request->all())  se creara el usuario e incluira los datos extras

por otro lado si de verdad quieres separar la informacion, en el modelo User

crea una reacion

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User_profiles');
}
```

cuando guardes la informacion tendras que guardarlo por separado, asi:

```
$user = User::Create($request->all()); 
$profile = new User_profiles;
$profile->user_id = $user->id;
$profile->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
$profile->ciudad = $request->get('ciudad');
$profile->telefono = $request->get('telefono');
$profile->save();
```

entonces cuando mandes a llamar al usuario podras llamar a su profile por la relacion

```
$user = User::find(1); //supongamos que devuelve el usuario con id 1
echo $user->name . " " .$user->profile->last_name;
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo y te comento, en realidad eso resolveria otros casos, cuando en realidad quiero realizar un registro y la relacion a otro de una vez. Vengo de usar Rails y con nested model forms lo solucionas, agregas en el modelo accepts_nested_attributes_for los atributos luego lo que vas a aceptar por el controller en el strong params
 y asunto resuelto. Pero en Laravel ando como perdido xD.... Aviso el resultado bro! Thx

Comment: En esta situación como seria el caso:
`protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }`

Comment: Listo Bro, Lo solucione asi:
`$user =User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        $user->user_profile()->save(new UserProfile);`